# Deleting arrays of same elements in 2 dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am wondering how you would go about deleting arrays that contain the same elements in a 2 dimensional array.

For example:

```
let 2dArr = [ [1, 2, 3],
              [3, 2, 1],
              [2, 4, 5],
              [4, 5, 2],
              [4, 3, 1] ];
```

This array would delete the second and fourth elements, returning the 2d array:

```
returnedArr = [ [1, 2, 3],
                [2, 4, 5],
                [4, 3, 1] ];
```

How exactly could this be done, preserving the 2d array? I could only think to loop through elements, comparing elements via a sort, and deleting them as you go along, but this would result in an indexing error if an element is deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using [`reduce`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwijlYD23oX1AhXUS2wGHV0WBFMQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AOvVaw1rZ36_gx-fT2lgEYKcfeI5) and [`Set`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwigiKCK34X1AhX7SWwGHetbCrcQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FSet&usg=AOvVaw3wy4IxrqjraA-uZKoQltnf) as:

```js
let twodArr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 2, 1],
  [2, 4, 5],
  [4, 5, 2],
  [4, 3, 1],
];

const set = new Set();

const result = twodArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const key = [...curr].sort((a, b) => a - b).join();
  if (!set.has(key)) {
    set.add(key);
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also use filter as:

```js
let twodArr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [3, 2, 1],
  [2, 4, 5],
  [4, 5, 2],
  [4, 3, 1],
];

const set = new Set();

const result = twodArr.filter((curr) => {
  const key = [...curr].sort((a, b) => a - b).join();
  return !set.has(key) ? (set.add(key), true) : false;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Need numeric sort. Works fine here only because  all are single digit

Comment: @charlietfl modified the code. Thanks for pointing out the mistake...

Comment: Just an *oversight*, never a mistake!

Answer (score 1):

```
const seen = []

const res = array.filter((item) => {
  let key = item.sort().join()
  if(!seen.includes(key)){
    seen.push(key)
    return item
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash map

```js
let arr = [ [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1],[2, 4, 5],[4, 5, 2],[4, 3, 1] ];
let obj = {}
let final = []

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  // create a key
  let sorted = [...arr[i]].sort((a,b)=> a- b).join`,`
  // check if this is not present in our hash map
  // add value to final out and update hash map accordingly
  if(!obj[sorted]){
    obj[sorted] = true
    final.push(arr[i])
  }
}

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Array.prototype.filter() and a Set as thisArg

```js
let arr = [ [1, 2, 3],
              [3, 2, 1],
              [2, 4, 5],
              [4, 5, 2],
              [4, 3, 1] ];


let res = arr.filter(function(e){
    const sorted = [...e].sort((a,b) => a-b).join('|');
    return this.has(sorted) ? false : this.add(sorted)    
},new Set)

console.log(res)
```